# What's the best practice to wait for fetch call in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my App.js script it looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

function App() {

  const [colorsData, setColorsData] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme?hex=0047AB&rgb=0,71,171&hsl=215,100%,34%&cmyk=100,58,0,33&mode=analogic&count=6`
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setColorsData(data))
  }, [])

  console.log(colorsData);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{colorsData ? colorsData.colors[0].hex.value : "Loading..."}</h1>
      <img src={colorsData ? colorsData.colors[0].image.named : "Loading..."} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Instead of checking if there's `colorsData` or not in every element which approach should I use for more clean code? If I don't check if there's `colorsData`, I get an error for undefined.

Comment: React beta docs have extensive info on this https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good people at [Vercel](https://vercel.com) created a great react hook library called SWR (stale while revalidate)

[SWR documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/)

> The name “SWR” is derived from stale-while-revalidate, a HTTP cache invalidation strategy popularized by HTTP RFC 5861. SWR is a strategy to first return the data from cache (stale), then send the fetch request (revalidate), and finally come with the up-to-date data.

Reasons to use instead of creating your own hook (from their website):

- Fast, lightweight and reusable data fetching
- Built-in cache and request deduplication
- Real-time experience
- Transport and protocol agnostic
- SSR / ISR / SSG support
- TypeScript ready
- React Native

Even more reasons (not bulleted to save space):

Fast page navigation, Polling on interval, Data dependency, Revalidation on focus, Revalidation on network recovery, Local mutation (Optimistic UI), Smart error retry, Pagination and scroll position recovery, and React Suspense

Implementation example:

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'

// you can use any fetcher with SWR, this is just a wrapper for the native fetch function
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

function App() {
  const url = `https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme?hex=0047AB&rgb=0,71,171&hsl=215,100%,34%&cmyk=100,58,0,33&mode=analogic&count=6`

  // error is optional, if you want to show your user that an error occured
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{colorsData ? data.colors[0].hex.value : "Loading..."}</h1>
      <img src={colorsData ? data.colors[0].image.named : "Loading..."} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Happy to help and spread the word of SWR! Also, if you go with this solution, would you mind marking it as the answer? It helps me gain some reputation here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom hook like:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useData(url) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading };
}

function App() {
  const { data, loading } = useData(
    "https://www.thecolorapi.com/scheme?hex=0047AB&rgb=0,71,171&hsl=215,100%,34%&cmyk=100,58,0,33&mode=analogic&count=6"
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        "Loading..."
      ) : (
        <>
          <h1>{data.colors[0].hex.value}</h1>
          <img src={data.colors[0].image.named} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```